# Is "nodetool scrub" and "sstablescrub" safe to run on cassandra node?

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

I was trying to run nodetool repair on cassandra node in production environment and this was not successfull, It was giving below error

**Validation failed in /10.253.189.222 (progress: 0%)

DEBUG [ReadRepairStage:99093] 2018-11-22 06:29:35,411 ReadCallback.java:234 - Digest mismatch:
org.apache.cassandra.service.DigestMismatchException: Mismatch for key DecoratedKey(5889678124560878183, 74e024839ef04bc1b14122ac99255dd6) (74aa9a679d7ddfa104c0666f277714b6 vs 9c7fadd13350462813b6ebdb035e2e9d)
                at org.apache.cassandra.service.DigestResolver.resolve(DigestResolver.java:85) ~[apache-cassandra-3.0.9.jar:3.0.9]
                at org.apache.cassandra.service.ReadCallback$AsyncRepairRunner.run(ReadCallback.java:225) ~[apache-cassandra-3.0.9.jar:3.0.9]
                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_131]
                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_131]
                at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_131]**

Is it safe to run "nodetool scrub" and "sstablescrub"? Will there be any data loss? Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

You can try nodetool repair on particular keyspace and table so most of the table you will able to repair if all the table not having issue. Also, you can run nodetool scrub on keyspace and table.